# Как в Pandas Series выбрать ключи по значению?

Tags: python, pandas

Допустим, у меня есть Pandas Series большой длины, его индексы (ключи) - строки. Я хочу получить все ключи, для которых значение равно определённому числу. При этом я не хочу вносить в этот Series никаких изменений. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать лучшим образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [39]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3,1,2,3,1], index=list('abcdefg'))

In [40]: s
Out[40]:
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    1
e    2
f    3
g    1
dtype: int64

In [41]: s==1
Out[41]:
a     True
b    False
c    False
d     True
e    False
f    False
g     True
dtype: bool

In [42]: s.index[s==1]
Out[42]: Index(['a', 'd', 'g'], dtype='object')
```